# unit testing async task in csharp

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, async-await

I'm new to unit testing and async operations in visual studio/c#. Appreciate any help on this.

**My Main class**

```
class Foo 
{
    public async Task<string> GetWebAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://hotmail.com");
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGet()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    foo.GetWebAsync().ContinueWith((k) =>
    {
        Console.Write(k);
        Assert.IsNotNull(null, "error");
    });
}
```

Comment: This piece of code looks odd to me `var response = await client.GetAsync("https://hotmail.com");
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.....why not two responses and wait all, when all?

Comment: @Hackerman I'm new and the code is not perfect, can you please help fix it with an answer?

Comment: You can create another similar question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make the Test async as well

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestGet() {
    var foo = new Foo();
    var result = await foo.GetWebAsync();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result, "error");
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, quick question, sometimes my `Console.Write("..")` output appears in TestExplorer besides stack trace (if error) once I select a specific test and sometimes don't, any idea?

Comment: Do you think my implementation for `GetWebAsync` is correct?

Comment: @user2727195 for a start it is ok. there is always room for improvement but that leads into a whole other topic of OOP design which is out of scope for this question

Comment: When do we have to call `ConfigureAwait(false)`?